# Menus are hiding behind Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site in Bootstrap 3 here http://213.239.217.181/carboot/

I may get downvotes because people will say *what have you tried* or show us the code *you have tried*

But its been a whole day I am struggling with this issue.

On *iPhone 5*, when you open menus with Toggle button, some menus are hidden behind the slider image, but they should not!

Slider is inside `<section id="slider">` and I have tried every possible thing but cannot figure out how to solve my issue.

[image: Not displaying well]

***This is how it should be displaying.***

[image: displaying Correctly]

Comment: Did you use latest bootstrap framework. Because this may occur in deprecated framework. Mostly problem with responsive menu.

Comment: @CodeLord You are right, I just updated my Bootstrap CSS to latest one and it solved my issue. Please post it as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Bootstrap framework to latest.Because this may occur in deprecated framework. Mostly problem with responsive menu. I have same issue with responsive menu and it is not working in mobile devices. Same issue with your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your bootstrap theme set a `max-height` to the nav-bar element, inside a media query, and this trim the menù:

```
.navbar-collapse { max-height :340px }
```

Override it in your CSS, just like i've done in Chrome Dev Tool :

[image: Solution in Chrome Dev Tool]

Comment: this may hamper other device. There will be unnecessary 340px space.

Comment: In what manner? max height is not necessary: there will be no unnecessary 340px space if the rule will be removed...

Comment: @Giacomo Paita Thanks for figuring issue ... It is solved ... But now I am worried that it may show something wrong in other devices ...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:

`.navbar-collapse { max-height: none;}`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Try by giving css Z-index property to say 999 to your menu container id.For ex:

Html Code:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Css:

```
#menu{
z-index:999;
```

}